# R "openxlsx" package not maintaining formatting

Tags: r, openxlsx

*R Version: 4.0.1 (2020-06-06),   openxlsx Version: 4.2.4*

I'm having formatting issues with the `openxlsx` package. When I load a workbook (`loadWorkbook`) and then save it again (`saveWorkbook`), formatting such as **text color**, **cell alignment**, **"wrap text" status**, and **font** are **reset to default**.

I've identified the issue down to a simple use case: If I create a sample `sample_in.xlsx` file with a table of random values and text colors, and then run the below code, all of the text color is lost. Am I doing something wrong?

```
library(openxlsx)

# Load Workbook
wb <- loadWorkbook("sample_in.xlsx")

# Save Workbook
saveWorkbook(wb, file = "sample_out.xlsx")
```

After this code, the `sample_out.xlsx` file contains no formatting. I'm not sure what's going on! It worked before I updated to the latest version of `openxlsx`.

Thanks!

Comment: This is indeed a bug, yet it has not been resolved. See this [link](https://github.com/ycphs/openxlsx/issues/207) for an update from its developer.